# What is the difference between DDR3 and GDDR5?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, ddr3

As I said, Before I begin, this is **not** a duplicate of [What is the different between DDR3 and GDDR3](https://superuser.com/questions/704168/what-is-the-difference-between-gddr3-and-ddr3), so idk why it has been marked as a duplicate this is an entirely different question. What im talking about is what is the difference between DDR3 and GDDR5? I have a desktop PC, and I am looking to upgrade the ram from 4GB to 8GB. But as I have discovered GDDR5, im not sure which one is better.

Can someone help me with the difference? (Ports are PCIe like all desktops)

Comment: Dont see how its different? GDDR cant be used for system memory.

Comment: GDDR5 is used for graphics cards, not system memory.

Comment: Read [**Post1**](https://gaming.msi.com/article/gddr5-or-ddr3-does-matter-with-nvidia-geforce-gtx850m-graphics) and [**Post2**](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/whats-the-difference-between-ddr3-memory-and-gddr5-memory.186408/)... Apparently  DDR3 is also used with Graphics cards, you can buy one here for example [**Amazon Card**](http://www.amazon.com/PNY-GeForce-DDR3-Graphics-VCGGT7302D3LXPB/dp/B00KYCTD34)... Post1 gives some good benchmark differences from the performance side where it seems to get more FPS on GDDR5. Are you referring to graphics card or system RAM?

Comment: Referring to system ram

Comment: Word for word, your post is kind of confusing to me if you're referring to a **regular desktop PC** and **system RAM** though. You ask about **DDR3** and **GDDR5** but you're not referring to Graphics memory but you also list **PCIe**. Here's a post that talks about the PS4 using GDDR5 for its system memory with their system architecture but  a PS4 isn't a standard/normal PC. [**PS4 Article**](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/general-discussion-30/help-me-understand-sony-using-gddr5-ram-for-the-ps-1425644/). Please confirm if you are mistaken about your understanding of this technology.

Comment: They are completely different things.  The G in GDDR is for graphics.  GDDR memory is high speed memory specifically manufactured specifically for video cards and will not work with your desktop for memory.  You need to buy memory that is compatible with your desktop.  Go to Crucial.com to find memory that will work with your desktop.

Comment: GDDR5 cannot be used as system memory on your particular system. Your system uses DDR3, the differences between GDDR3 and DDR3 are nearly identically to the differences between GDDR5 and DDR3 only difference would be speed.

Comment: Give a look [here](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/whats-the-difference-between-ddr3-memory-and-gddr5-memory.186408/). Below this and in general you should always refer to the manuals of your motherboard, Note that even current version of the BIOS vs  the updated one can make some difference in the possibility to handle different kind of components. Some OS are able to overcome some limit of the BIOS, but we are going so far from your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a desktop PC, and I am looking to upgrade the RAM from 4GiB to 8GiB.

Ok, so far so good. Millions of people have done that before...

> But as I have discovered GDDR5, I'm not sure which one is best.

GDDR5 will not fit in any standard motherboard. That means you need to add more DDR3.

(That is not to say that you cannot design a motherboard which works with GDDR5. But it is not standard and it certainly will not work if you have to ask.)